# How to fix these hard Edges in Render?

Tags: rendering, edges

[image]

They are not UV seems and I recalculated the normals. Does anybody have any idea of what it would be?

here is the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1te2NBPLglBqUzw8PGbYGmgm85URY6SEo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sometimes it can be caused by normal map but this really looks like "terminator" effect. Either add more lights, hide that area from camera or add more geometry. Environment lighting there is going to be too flat so hdri and / or one or 2 additonal lamps could eliminate the problem

Comment: The Smooth shading will smooth the surface appearance but not its outlines, it will stay sharp, if you want your object to have a real smooth silhouette, I guess you'll need to add fake topology with the Subsurf modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: render]

Your issue is indeed caused by the model topology. One option is to use **Subsurf modifier** to smooth out the mesh. The problem with this approach is that you will loose lowpolyness of this object. Current 735 vs 70,370 verts after 3 level of subdivision (this level reduce artifacts completely).

As an alternative you can just smooth it with **Sculpt Smooth** brush.

1. Go to **Sculpt Mode**.
2. Select **Smooth brush** and set **Strength** to low value - I've used **0.1**.
3. Smooth it!

[image: smooth]